# Creating simple city streets

Tags: java, random, terrain

I am trying to create an algorithm for creating a simple 2D city road system. Its not even going to be procedural, just confined to a small grid.

By simple, I mean something like this:
[image]

I have thought to just shoot random length lines from the edges but that doesn't give me the connected-ness look that I want.

I also tried randomly placing nodes and connecting them with L shaped lines but that didn't produce good results either.

Any links to resources, theory, or sample code would be highly appreciated!

P.S It can be in any language. I just need to know the concept behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating terrain, e.g. mountain ranges, fractal structures are often used, so perhaps a similar idea could be used here. Do a Google search for "fractal terrain generation" to read more. For the case of generating a street layout, you could try the following algorithm (this is just off the top of my head, so no guarantees that this will actually look nice):

- Start with a rectangular area.
- Put a small, random number of streets spanning from one edge to another at random locations. Randomness ensures variation in the layout. An example of this single iteration could look like the example you give in the question but simpler, I'd guess 1-4 lines would be reasonable.
- The streets you just created divide your area into rectangular blocks. Apply the same division algorithm recursively to each block, of course choosing different random numbers each time.
- After 3 or 4 iterations you should have a reasonably complex street network. You can make streets created in subsequent iterations somewhat narrower so that you have a few main streets in the city, some more major streets and a whole lot of minor streets.

Answer (score 1):

I would create random blocks with different sizes and than add these together with leaving a space between each block which represent the streets.

In detail I would make an 2d array. Put the first random block for example in one corner and set all the fields covered by the block with an id for non-street tile. Surround the whole block with street tile. And than repeat the process with the next block by putting it next to the street tiles from the first block. Do this till all fields in the array are either non street tiles or street tiles.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting solution that should work.. I'll try it thanks!